# Do "Ding", "Sache", and "Zeug" have a crude connotation?

Tags: synonym

As a general term for *things*, or more informally, *stuff*, when would you use *Ding*, *Sache*, or *Zeug*? Does *Zeug* have any crude meaning, like *crap*, as in asking your elderly German host where you could set down your items?
There are many social settings in both languages where you could safely say *things* instead of *items* or *stuff* instead of *things*, but not *crap* instead of *stuff*.
If *Zeug* doesn't have any crude meaning, are there other words that do?

Answer (score 11):

**Zeug** is not really crude, but someone could understand — or mean — it slightly pejorative.
**Sachen** is always neutral and implies some kind of respect for things.

When you want to be polite, you should prefer *Sachen* rather than *Zeug* or *Dinge*.
**Ding** is mostly used in singular form:

> Was ist denn das für ein Ding?

When asking where one can set down his items, nobody would say

> Wo kann ich meine Dinge abstellen?

Much better is:

> Wo kann ich meine Sachen abstellen?

Some possible use for *Dinge*, mostly when referring to abstract … well … “things”:

> Ich habe noch ein paar Dinge zu erledigen (*Dinge* means tasks)
>   Mir sind einige Dinge aufgefallen (*Dinge* means items or issues)
>   Die Dinge sind komplizierter als Sie denken (*Dinge* means circumstances or interrelations)

I can’t tell you a rule for it, but mostly — not always — you can use *Sache(n)* instead of *Ding(e)* and vice versa.

**To be crude** you could use *Kram* or *Krempel*. Even more crude would be *Müll* or *Mist*.

> Wo kann ich meinen Müll abladen?

would be very bad slang for saying “Where can I set down my items?”

If your elderly host hates you after some time he could say:

> Wie lange soll der Mist noch hierbleiben?

or

> Wann schaffen Sie endlich Ihren Kram weg?

Comment: Even more colloquial you cold say: Wo kann ich meinen Scheiß abstellen? But only with friends or younger people I guess .. at least that was the first thing I would say :D

Comment: For collections of "useless stuff" there's also *Tand*, *Ramsch*, *Plunder* [and many more](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Plunder).

Comment: @user19199: This is the best translation for "crap" in this context, imho.

Answer (score 4):

For your example:

> Where can I store my stuff?

You would say

> Wo kann ich meine Sachen lassen/abstellen/verstauen?

While you can say *mein Zeug*, it is more colloquial than *meine Sachen*.

A more crude term would be *Krempel*, and stronger still *Gerümpel*.

Answer (score 3):

Zeug ist zwar äußerst vage, aber nicht notwendig abwertend für diverse Sachen. Es kommt auch in Zaumzeug, Werkzeug, Zeugwart und Zeughaus vor.

Auch Kram ist nicht unbedingt unfreundlich, bezeichnet aber allenfalls ironisch eine wertvolle Sammlung von Sachen. Krempel ist noch mehr auf unspezifisches, wertloses Allerlei gemünzt. Mundarten bieten hier auch eine Fülle an Begriffen, Geraffel in Bayern.

Crap dagegen würde ich mit Schrott oder Müll übersetzen.

Comment: Shouldn't that answer be in English?

Comment: @Stephie: Nein. Wer Fragen zur deutschen Sprache hat sollte in der Lage sein, sich den Sinn der Antwort, notfalls mit Hilfsmitteln, zu erschließen. Zur Not kann man auch in den Kommentaren noch mal nachfragen.

Comment: Die Sturheit hat eigentlich ein -1 verdient. Natürlich hat die Antwort in Englisch zu sein. Das wurde schon auf Meta diskutiert, und es gibt gute Gründe, warum Fragen zur deutschen Sprache in Englisch gestellt und beantwortet werden.

Comment: Wie sollen dann Menschen hier eine Frage stellen und verstehen, die sich zwar für Deutsch interessieren, aber kein Englisch sprechen? Hier geht's um Deutsch, also kann man auch auf Deutsch antworten. Es sei denn, der Fragesteller macht deutlich, dass er Antworten auf Deutsch nicht versteht. Da Scarbo aber nach sehr feinen Bedeutungsunterschieden fragt, die nur fortgeschrittene Sprecher interessieren können, wird er oder sie die Antwort sicher verstehen können – sonst könnte er dieses Wissen sowieso nicht umsetzen.

Comment: @what Wer kein Englisch versteht, stellt die Frage auf Deutsch und bekommt eine Antwort in Deutsch. Die Frage ist aber in Englisch gestellt, ich wette also, dass der Fragesteller Englisch versteht. Wie gut sein Deutsch ist, ist fraglich, und auch wenn es in deinen Augen eine Sache für fortgeschrittene Sprecher ist, so betrachte ich dies als sehr fundamental und durchaus auch für absolute Anfänger interessant. Und dass diese Englisch besser als Deutsch beherrschen ist nicht unwahrscheinlich.

Comment: @Em1: "Natürlich hat die Antwort in Englisch zu sein. " Weil Du das sagst, oder wieso? Eben wenn Du die Diskussionen auf Meta gelesen hättest wüsstest Du, dass es mindestens ebenso gute Gründe gibt auf Deutsch zu antworten. Wenn Du deutsche Antworten nicht magst - was hindert Dich diese zu überlesen? Ignorier sie doch einfach.

Comment: @userunknown [Ironie an] Oh, tut mir leid, dass mir entgangen war, dass du dem Englischen nicht mächtig bist und daher in Deutsch antwortest. [Ironie aus] — Oder was war dein Grund, warum du nicht in der Lage warst, in Englisch zu schreiben? Faulheit? Trotz? Aufständisch, rebellisch?

Comment: @Em1: Deutsch lernt man, wenn man es benutzt, wie alle anderen Sprachen auch. Deutsch auf Englisch zu unterrichten ist kontraproduktiv und schlließt, wie schon oft erörtert, viele aus. Die Frage muss wenn, dann lauten: Wieso ist nicht auf Deutsch gefragt worden?